# Skip rows with blank cell in particular column

Tags: vba, excel, xls

Please advise me how to change my code to select rows only if they have a value in BC column (ignore complete row if cell in BC column is blank):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Range("A:a,b:b,c:c,e:e,bc:bc").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add          
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to ignore row #11 if both B11 and C11 are blank or ignore row #11 if either B11 or C11 are blank??

Comment: I want to ignore complete row if BC3 is blank

Answer (score 0):

First run your code as is.   Then perform the row deletions in the added workbook:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, I As Long, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "BC").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = N To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Cells(I, "BC")
        If IsEmpty(r) Then
            r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ok it will delete the blank rows but what about other filters @tigeravatar

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    Set wsData = ActiveSheet
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add

    With Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Columns("BK"))
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, wsData.Range("A:A,B:B,F:F,I:I,H:H,BK:BK")).Copy
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    wsNew.Move

    Set wsData = Nothing
    Set wsNew = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Set wsData = ActiveSheet
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
With Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Columns("BK"))
.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
.AutoFilter 1, "<>"
Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, wsData.Range("A:A,B:B,F:F,I:I,H:H,BK:BK")).Copy
wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
.AutoFilter
End With
wsNew.Move
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsNew = Nothing end sub
further filter column BL date current month or prev month then BM Pending/Resolv

Comment: please advise for further filter

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a filter:

1. Filter on column BC by unchecking (Blanks)
2. Copy the columns
3. Paste into a new worksheet or workbook

If it has to be VBA, here are two codes that will perform as desired.
This first code uses the autofilter:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet

    Set wsData = ActiveSheet
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add

    With Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Columns("BC"))
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, wsData.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,E:E,BC:BC")).Copy
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    wsNew.Move

    Set wsData = Nothing
    Set wsNew = Nothing

End Sub
```

This second, alternative code uses a find loop:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim strFirst As String

    Set rngFound = Columns("BC").Find("*", Cells(Rows.Count, "BC"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Set rngCopy = rngFound
        Do
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, rngFound)
            Set rngFound = Columns("BC").Find("*", rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
        Sheets.Add
        Intersect(rngCopy.Parent.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,E:E,BC:BC"), rngCopy.EntireRow).Copy
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        ActiveSheet.Move
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set rngCopy = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I am another issue with the result... with ref to 1st program if i want to filter it further with another column after BC I want to filter it with BD which is date column. I want to filter with current month & previous month.... then I want to filter it by BE which has 2 values RESOLVED & PENDING.... plz assist

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, usrname
usrname = UCase(Environ("UserName"))
Set wsData = ActiveSheet
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
wsNew.Name = "test"
With Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Columns("BK"))
.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
.AutoFilter 1, "<>"
Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, wsData.Range("E:E,F:F,G:G,A:A,BK:BK,BL:BL,bn:bn,bo:bo")).Copy
wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
.AutoFilter
End With
wsNew.Move
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsNew = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: can anybody help if i can auto filter multiple columns before paste the data to new sheet

Comment: You should probably start a new question because what you're asking is fundamentally different from your original question

Comment: yes it is.... because I need further requirement in my excel sheet.... plz advise